# Hai , I am using react formik for post and edit method in single components I am facing some difficulty here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, dom, formik

Problem is when I am updating the form and page redirect to list page then when we click on the name of the edit form at that time it will shows the old data not what I entered the current data.
This is the problem I am facing

`# I tried with some of the react formik methods but it wont help me to updating dom properly so please someone help with this, give some idea thanks in advance.

#code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import moment from 'moment'
import * as Yup from "yup";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";
import { Form, FormikProvider, useFormik } from "formik";
// material
import { LoadingButton } from "@mui/lab";
import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker';
import {
  Box,
  Card,
  Grid,
  Stack,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  FormHelperText,
  ToggleButtonGroup,
  ToggleButton,
  Alert,
  Autocomplete,
  CircularProgress,
  InputAdornment,
} from "@mui/material";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
// utils
import { fData } from "../../utils/formatNumber";
import { UploadAvatar } from "../../../src/components/upload/index";
import countries from "../../data/countries";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "../../redux/store";
import {
  postBranch,
  postBranchPhoto,
  updateIsBranchDone,
} from "../../redux/slices/dashboard";
import { setGlobalState, useGlobalState } from "src/contexts/GlobalState";
import { postDefaultBranch } from "src/redux/slices/branch";
import apiUrls from "../../config/api-urls";
import useIsMountedRef from "../../hooks/useIsMountedRef";
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";
import PhoneInput from "src/components/PhoneInput";
import { ApiHelper } from "src/redux/api-helpers";
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import {
  useFindBranchByIdQuery,
  useFindBranchQuery,
} from "src/redux/apiServices/branchService";
import { AccountCircle } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { set } from "lodash";

var data = require("../../data/timezones.json");

function countryToFlag(isoCode) {
  return typeof String.fromCodePoint !== "undefined"
    ? isoCode
      .toUpperCase()
      .replace(/./g, (char) =>
        String.fromCodePoint(char.charCodeAt(0) + 127397)
      )
    : isoCode;
}

const apiKey = "AIzaSyBz0QZLgUyySO2mWAy5KcOHFXMpWkGYPOA";
const mapApiJs = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js";

//load googleMap Api js
function loadAsyncScript(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    Object.assign(script, {
      type: "text/javascript",
      async: true,
      src,
    });
    script.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(script));
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
}

EditBranchProfile.propTypes = {
  currentUser: PropTypes.object,
};

let handleTimeout;

export default function EditBranchProfile({ isAdd, branchDetails }) {

  // data from store
  const searchInput = useRef(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [defaultCompany] = useGlobalState("defaultCompany");
  const {
    user,
    branchdefault,
    branchName,
    companyName,
    company,
    branch: authBranch,
  } = useAuth();
  const { err_msg, branch, branch_photo, isBranchDone } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.dashboard
  );
  

  console.log(branch,"branches from edit")



  // const params = useParams();
  // let [defaultBranch] = useGlobalState("defaultBranch"); // defaultBranch
  // // RTKQ
  // const { isLoading, data: branchDetails = {} } = useFindBranchByIdQuery(params?.id || defaultBranch?.id, { skip: !params?.id && !defaultBranch?.id })
  // console.log(branchDetails, 'branchDetails')

  // const branchDetails = params.id ? branchData : defaultBranch

  // State
  const [placeAddress, setAddress] = useState({});
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState(
    branchDetails?.address ? [{ label: branchDetails.address, id: null }] : []
  );
  const [isPlacesLoading, setIsPlacesLoading] = useState(false);
  const [holiday, setHoliday] = useState([]);
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState({ defaultbranch: false });
  const [alignment, setAlignment] = useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date());


  // Hooks
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const isMountedRef = useIsMountedRef();
  const matches = useMediaQuery("(min-width:600px)");

  //Multiple buttons data
  const holidays = [
    { id: 1, day: "Sunday" },
    { id: 2, day: "Monday" },
    { id: 3, day: "Tuesday" },
    { id: 4, day: "Wednesday" },
    { id: 5, day: "Thursday" },
    { id: 6, day: "Friday" },
    { id: 7, day: "Saturday" },
  ];
  const teamSizeOptions = [
    { label: "1-10", code: 10 },
    { label: "11-50", code: 50 },
    { label: "51-150", code: 100 },
    { label: "150+", code: 150 },
  ];
  const getTeamSizeOptions = (label) => {
    let option = teamSizeOptions.find((item) => item.label === label);
    if (!option) return teamSizeOptions;

    return teamSizeOptions.filter((item) => {
      return item.code <= option.code;
    });
  };

  // const extractAddress = (place) => {

  //   const placeAddress = {
  //     city: "",
  //     state: "",
  //     country: "",
  //     zip: "",
  //     place_id: "",
  //   }

  //   if (!Array.isArray(place?.address_components)) {
  //     return placeAddress;
  //   }

  // }
  const phoneRegExp = /^[0-9]{6,13}$/;
  const SUPPORTED_FORMATS = [
    "image/jpg",
    "image/jpeg",
    "image/gif",
    "image/png",
  ];

  const NewBranchSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string().required("Name is required"),
    // contact_mobile: Yup.string().required('Mobile number is required').matches(/^[0-9\s]+$/, 'Only numbers are allowed for this field '),
    // contact_mobile: Yup.string()
    //   .required("Phone number is required")
    //   .min(6,"Phone number is not valid")
    //   .max(13,"Phone number is not valid")
    //   .matches(phoneRegExp, "Phone number is not valid"),
    // c_code: Yup.string().required("Country code is required"),
    address: Yup.mixed().required("address is required"),
    time_zone: Yup.string().required("Time Zone is required"),
    total_people: Yup.mixed().required("Team Size is required"),
    pin: Yup.string().required("ZipCode is required"),
    holiday: Yup.array().required("Holiday is required"),
    country: Yup.string().required("country is required"),
    state: Yup.string().required("State is required"),
    city: Yup.string().required("City is required"),
    opt_from: Yup.string().required("Operates From is required"),
    opt_to: Yup.string().required("Operates To is required"),
    // avatarUrl: Yup.mixed().required('Avatar is required')
    // .test(
    //   "fileFormat",
    //   "Unsupported Format",
    //   value => value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type)
    // )
    // .test(
    //   "fileSize",
    //   "File too large",
    //   value => value && value.size <= FILE_SIZE
    // )
  });
  const formik = useFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: {
      name: isAdd ? "" : branchDetails ? branchDetails.name : "",
      contact_mobile: isAdd ? "": branchDetails ? branchDetails.contact_mobile: "",
      c_code: isAdd ? "" : branchDetails ? branchDetails.c_code : "IN",
      total_people: isAdd ? "": branchDetails ? branchDetails.total_people: "",
      time_zone: isAdd ? "" : branchDetails ? branchDetails.time_zone : "",
      address: isAdd ? "" : branchDetails?.address || null,
      country: isAdd ? "" : branchDetails ? branchDetails.country : "",
      state: isAdd ? "" : branchDetails ? branchDetails.state : "",
      city: isAdd ? "" : branchDetails ? branchDetails.city : "",
      pin: isAdd ? "" : branchDetails ? branchDetails.pin : "",
      opt_from: moment(isAdd ? "00:00" : branchDetails ? branchDetails.opt_from : "00:00","HH:mm"),
      opt_to: moment(isAdd ? "00:00" : branchDetails ? branchDetails.opt_to : "00:00","HH:mm"),
      // avatarUrl: isAdd ? "":`${apiUrls.BRANCH_PHOTO}${branchDetails ? branchDetails.logo : branch ? branch.logo : ""}`,
      // avatarUrl: `${apiUrls.BRANCH_PHOTO}${branch ? branch.logo : ''}`,
      avatarUrl:isAdd ? " " : `${apiUrls.BRANCH_PHOTO}${branchDetails ? branchDetails.logo : ''}`,
      logo: null,
      holiday: isAdd ? [] : branchDetails ? branchDetails.holiday : "",

      // defaultbranch: branch ? branch.defaultbranch : 'YES',
    },
    validationSchema: NewBranchSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm, setErrors }) => {
      setSubmitting(true);
      try {
        let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(values));
        data["company_id"] = defaultCompany ? defaultCompany.id : company.id;
        data["created_by"] = user ? user.id : "";
        // data['c_code'] = data['c_code','phone'];
        data["opt_from"] = moment(data.opt_from).format("HH:mm");
        data["opt_to"] = moment(data.opt_to).format("HH:mm");
        data["holiday"] = holiday;
        if (!isAdd) {
          values["logo"] = branch?.logo;
          dispatch(postBranch(data,branch.id));
          resetForm();
        } else {
          dispatch(postBranch(data));
          resetForm({values:''})
          
        }
        // if (isBranchDone) {
        //   resetForm();
        // }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        if (isMountedRef.current) {
          setErrors({ afterSubmit: error.message || err_msg });
          setSubmitting(false);
        }
      }
    },
  });


 
  const {
    errors,
    values,
    touched,
    handleSubmit,
    isSubmitting,
    setFieldValue,
    getFieldProps,
    setFieldTouched,
    setValues,
    isValid,
    dirty,
    handleReset
  } = formik;

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      dispatch(updateIsBranchDone(false))
    }
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    if (err_msg) {
      errors.afterSubmit = err_msg;
    }
    if (branch) {
      setHoliday(branch.holiday);
      if (!branch_photo && values["avatarUrl"].path) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        fetch(values["avatarUrl"].preview).then((response) => {
          response.blob().then((blob) => {
            formData.append("photo", blob, values["avatarUrl"].path);
            dispatch(postBranchPhoto(formData, branch.id));
          });
        });
      }
    }
    if (isBranchDone) {
      enqueueSnackbar(err_msg || isAdd ? 'Branch created successfully' : 'Branch updated successfully', {
        variant: err_msg ? 'error' : 'success'
      })
      setValues({values})
      navigate('/dashboard/branches')
    }
  }, [err_msg, isBranchDone]);
  const handleDrop = useCallback(
    (acceptedFiles) => {
      const file = acceptedFiles[0];
      if (file) {
        setFieldValue("avatarUrl", {
          ...file,
          preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        });
      }
    },
    [setFieldValue]
  );

  
  const handleButton = (button) => {
    if (holiday.includes(button)) {
      setHoliday(holiday.filter((el) => el !== button));
    } else {
      setHoliday([...holiday, button]);
    }
  };

  const handleAlignment = (event, newAlignment) => {
    if (newAlignment !== null) {
      setAlignment(newAlignment);
    }
  };

  const toggler = (event) => {
    setToggle({ ...toggle, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  const searchPlaces = ({ target }) => {
    let { value } = target;
    clearTimeout(handleTimeout);
    handleTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsPlacesLoading(true);
      ApiHelper({
        url: `${apiUrls.UTILS.ADDRESS}?search=${value}`,
        method: "get",
      })
        .then((res) => res.data)
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.error) {
            let places = res.data || [];
            places = places.map((item) => ({
              id: item.placeId,
              label: item.fullAddress,
            }));
            setPlaces(places);
          }
          setIsPlacesLoading(false);
        });
    }, 200);
  };

  const handlePlaseChange = (e, value) => {
    let { id, label } = value;
    setFieldTouched("address", true);
    if (!value.id) return;
    ApiHelper({
      url: `${apiUrls.UTILS.PLACE_DETAILS}?placeId=${id}`,
      method: "get",
    })
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.error) {
          let address = res.data;
          setValues({
            ...values,
            address: label,
            pin: address.pinCode || "",
            country: address.country || "",
            state: address.state || "",
            city: address.city || "",
          });
        }
      });
  };

  //   if(!defaultBranch) {
  // return <div>Loading...</div>
  //   }
  return (
    <FormikProvider 
        value={formik}
        validateOnMount
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        enableReinitialize={true}

    >
      <Form noValidate autoComplete="off" 
       onReset={handleReset}
      >
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
            <Card sx={{ py: 10, px: 3 }}>
              <Box sx={{ mb: 5 }}>
                <UploadAvatar
                  accept="image/*"
                  file={values.avatarUrl}
                  maxSize={3145728}
                  onDrop={handleDrop}
                  id="logo-photo"
                  error={Boolean(touched.avatarUrl && errors.avatarUrl)}
                  caption={
                    <Typography
                      variant="caption"
                      sx={{
                        mt: 2,
                        mx: "auto",
                        display: "block",
                        textAlign: "center",
                        color: "text.secondary",
                      }}
                    >
                      Allowed *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.png, *.gif
                      <br /> max size of {fData(3145728)}
                    </Typography>
                  }
                />
                <FormHelperText error sx={{ px: 2, textAlign: "center" }}>
                  {touched.avatarUrl && errors.avatarUrl}
                </FormHelperText>
              </Box>
            </Card>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
            <Card sx={{ p: 3 }}>
              <Stack spacing={3}>
              {errors.afterSubmit &&
            <Alert severity="error">{errors.afterSubmit}</Alert>}
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  label="Branch Name"
                  {...getFieldProps("name")}
                  error={Boolean(touched.name && errors.name)}
                  helperText={touched.name && errors.name}
                />
                {/* <PhoneInput
                label="Branch Mobile Number"
                  country={countries.find(
                    (country) => country.code === values.c_code
                  )}
                  onCountryChange={({ code }) => setFieldValue("c_code", code)}
                  text={values.contact_mobile}
                  onTextChange={({ target }) =>
                    setFieldValue("contact_mobile", target.value)
                  }
                  error={Boolean(
                    touched.contact_mobile && errors.contact_mobile
                  )}
                  helperText={touched.contact_mobile && errors.contact_mobile}
                /> */}

                <Autocomplete
                  fullWidth
                  value={values.total_people}
                  //need to change it as string option----
                  options={getTeamSizeOptions(company.team_size).map(
                    (option) => option.label
                  )}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      error={Boolean(
                        touched.total_people && errors.total_people
                      )}
                      helperText={touched.total_people && errors.total_people}
                      label="Branch Team Size"
                    />
                  )}
                  onChange={(e, value) => {
                    if (value) setFieldValue("total_people", value);
                  }}
                  sx={{ mb: 2 }}
                />
                {/* Address */}
                <Autocomplete
                  fullWidth
                  value={values.address}
                  options={places}
                  loading={isPlacesLoading}
                  onChange={handlePlaseChange}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      onChange={searchPlaces}
                      label="Address"
                      InputProps={{
                        ...params.InputProps,
                        endAdornment: (
                          <React.Fragment>
                            {isPlacesLoading ? (
                              <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />
                            ) : null}
                            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                          </React.Fragment>
                        ),
                      }}
                      // {...getFieldProps("address")}
                      error={touched.address && !!errors.address}
                      helperText={touched.address && errors.address}
                    />
                  )}
                />

                <Stack
                  direction={{ xs: "column", sm: "row" }}
                  spacing={{ xs: 3, sm: 2 }}
                >
                  <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    label="Country"
                    value={placeAddress.country}
                    {...getFieldProps("country")}
                    error={Boolean(touched.country && errors.country)}
                    helperText={touched.country && errors.country}
                  />

                  <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    label="State/Region"
                    value={placeAddress.state}
                    {...getFieldProps("state")}
                    error={Boolean(touched.state && errors.state)}
                    helperText={touched.state && errors.state}
                  />
                </Stack>

                <Stack
                  direction={{ xs: "column", sm: "row" }}
                  spacing={{ xs: 3, sm: 2 }}
                >
                  <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    label="City"
                    {...getFieldProps("city")}
                    error={Boolean(touched.city && errors.city)}
                    helperText={touched.city && errors.city}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    label="Zip/Pin Code"
                    {...getFieldProps("pin")}
                    error={Boolean(touched.pin && errors.pin)}
                    helperText={touched.pin && errors.pin}
                  />
                </Stack>

                <Stack
                  direction={{ xs: "column", sm: "row" }}
                  spacing={{ xs: 3, sm: 2 }}
                >
                  <Autocomplete
                    fullWidth
                    freeSolo
                    value={values.time_zone}
                    options={data.map((option) => option.text)}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField
                        {...params}
                        error={Boolean(touched.time_zone && errors.time_zone)}
                        helperText={touched.time_zone && errors.time_zone}
                        label="time_zone"
                        {...getFieldProps("state")}
                      />
                    )}
                    onChange={(e, value) => {
                      if (value) setFieldValue("time_zone", value);
                    }}
                    sx={{ mb: 2 }}
                  />


                  {/* <TextField
                    id="input-with-icon-adornment"
                    fullWidth
                    type="time"
                    // defaultValue={'05:10'}
                    label="Store opening time"
                    placeholder="Store start from"
                    InputProps={{
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                          <AccountCircle />
                        </InputAdornment>
                      ),
                    }}
                    {...getFieldProps("opt_from")}
                    InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                    error={Boolean(touched.opt_from && errors.opt_from)}
                    helperText={touched.opt_from && errors.opt_from}
                  /> */}

                  {/* <TimePicker
                    label="Store opening time"
                    value={values.opt_from}
                    onChange={(e, value) => {
                      if (value) setValue(value);
                    }}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                    {...getFieldProps("opt_from")}
                   
                    error={Boolean(touched.opt_from && errors.opt_from)}
                    helperText={touched.opt_from && errors.opt_from}
                  /> */}
                  <TimePicker
                    label="Store opening time"
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField
                      {...params}
                      fullWidth
                      onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('opt_from', true)}
                      error={Boolean(touched.opt_from && errors.opt_from)}
                      helperText={touched.opt_from && errors.opt_from}
                    />}
                    value={values.opt_from}
                    onChange={value => setFieldValue('opt_from', value)}

                  />
                  {/* <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    type="time"
                    label="Operates To"
                    // placeholder="Operates To"
                    {...getFieldProps('opt_to')}
                    error={Boolean(touched.opt_to && errors.opt_to)}
                    helperText={touched.opt_to && errors.opt_to}
                  /> */}
                  {/* <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    type="time"
                    label="Store closing time"
                    placeholder="Operates To"
                    {...getFieldProps("opt_to")}
                    InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                    error={Boolean(touched.opt_to && errors.opt_to)}
                    helperText={touched.opt_to && errors.opt_to}
                  /> */}
                  <TimePicker
                    label="Store closing time"
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField
                      {...params}
                      fullWidth
                      onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('opt_to', true)}
                      error={Boolean(touched.opt_to && errors.opt_to)}
                      helperText={touched.opt_to && errors.opt_to}
                    />}
                    value={values.opt_to}
                    onChange={value => setFieldValue('opt_to', value)}
                    InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}

                  />
                </Stack>
                {/* <Stack direction={{ xs: 'column', sm: 'row' }}
                  spacing={{ xs: 3, sm: 2 }}>
                  <Typography component="p" sx={{ mt: '8px' }}>
                    Default Branch
                  </Typography>
                  <Switch
                    onChange={toggler}
                    name="defaultbranch"
                    // checked={checkedValue}
                    
                    // {...getFieldProps('defaultbranch')}
                    // error={Boolean(touched.defaultbranch && errors.defaultbranch)}
                    // helperText={touched.defaultbranch && errors.defaultbranch}
                  />
                </Stack> */}
                <Stack
                  direction={{ xs: "column", sm: "row" }}
                  spacing={{ xs: 3, sm: 2 }}
                >
                  <Typography component="p" sx={{ mt: "8px" }}>
                    Weekly Off
                  </Typography>
                  <ToggleButtonGroup
                    // color="secondary"
                    value={holiday}
                    onChange={handleAlignment}
                    orientation={`${matches ? `horizontal` : `vertical`}`}
                    // exclusive
                    fullWidth
                  // onChange={handleChange}
                  // {...getFieldProps('holiday')}
                  //   error={Boolean(touched.holiday && errors.holiday)}
                  //   helperText={touched.holiday && errors.holiday}
                  >
                    {holidays.map((holiday) => (
                      <ToggleButton
                        key={holiday.id}
                        value={holiday.day}
                        onClick={() => handleButton(holiday.day)}
                      >
                        {holiday.day}
                      </ToggleButton>
                    ))}
                  </ToggleButtonGroup>
                </Stack>
                <Box
                  sx={{
                    mt: 3,
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "flex-start",
                  }}
                >

                  <LoadingButton
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    size="large"
                    loading={isSubmitting}
                    // disabled={!(isValid && dirty)}
                  >
                    {isAdd ? "Create Branch" : "Save Changes"}
                  </LoadingButton>
                </Box>
              </Stack>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Form>
    </FormikProvider>
  );
}
```

`